# What is (View view) in public void onButton1Click(View view)?

Tags: android, view

I know that onButton1Click is a method,
but what are (View view)?
Why do I have to put them there?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you bookmark https://developer.android.com/index.html and refer to it on a regular basis. It has Android training and design guides as well as the full reference of all the Android classes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the example from where you found onButton1Click? It sounds like the name of an `onClick` method that you found in code somewhere.

When declaring a `Button` in the layout.xml document, you can declare the `android:onClick` tag to refer to a method in the code. In this case, it sounds like you have:

```
    android:onClick = "onButton1Click"
```

in the xml file.

The `onButtonClick` refers to the method in your `Activity.java` file that you see with the (View view) parameter.

The first View refers to the type of the parameter (`View`) and the second "view" is the variable name of the parameter to be used throughout the method.

Answer (score 0):

Its the parameter-  the view that was clicked.  Its passed in case multiple views use the same on click handler and you need to tell which one was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

`View` `view` is whatever view (`Button`, `LinearLayout`, `EditText`) you set that method to be called on when it it clicked. As that method is defined in your layout file, it has to have a View associated to it.